# How to export xml to database - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml-database

I want to export xml file data to sql database table. Can anyone guide me for this?

Comment: Which database are you speaking from? Sql Server?

Comment: Do you already have a database with a suitable table? Will you do this many times or just once? Which database do you use?

Comment: I want to export data everyday. I have created a suitable table. sql server 2008.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET: How to insert XML document into SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574836/net-how-to-insert-xml-document-into-sql-server)

Comment: Hi Timwi, In that post there no mark of answer. Thats y i have posted my question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's an SQL Server, I already answered a similar Question. Have a look at the following posting:

[.NET: How to insert XML document into SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574836/net-how-to-insert-xml-document-into-sql-server/3574884#3574884)

You can use that small c# part to store your data. You only have to amend the table and column fields.

```
class Program
{
    private static void SaveXmlToDatabase(DbConnection connection,
          XmlDocument xmlToSave)
    {
       String sql = "INSERT INTO xmlTable(xmlColumn) VALUES (@xml)";

       using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
       {
          XPathNavigator nav = xmlToSave.CreateNavigator();
          string xml = nav.SelectSingleNode("/catalog/cd[title='Manowar']").InnerXml;

          command.CommandText = sql;
          command.Parameters.Add(
            new SqlParameter("@xml", SqlDbType.Xml) 
               {Value = new SqlXml(new XmlTextReader(xml
                           , XmlNodeType.Document, null)) });

          DbTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction();
          try
          {
             command.ExecuteNonQuery();
             trans.Commit();
          }
          catch (Exception)
          {
             trans.Rollback();
             throw;
          }
       }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(args.First());

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
            "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;");

        SaveXmlToDatabase(connection, document);

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to filter the fields from the xml file while passing it as the parameter to insert?

Comment: you could add a xpath query to filter the xml file.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more please.

Comment: Yes, you can do that with the XPathNavigator for example.

XPathNavigator nav = xmlToSave.CreateNavigator();
string xml = nav.SelectSingleNode("/catalog/cd[title='Manowar']").InnerXml;

Answer (score 1):

check below link for this

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/beginning-sql-server-2005-xml-programming/

you can find the solution.

Comment: The answer itself should contain the solution, not only link to it (as links become unaccessible after time)