# How to cast string to SqlXml

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, .net-2.0

I have a method that returns a well formed Xml **string**. How do I cast this string to SqlXml ?

Comment: This link may solve your problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574928/c-sql-whats-wrong-with-sqldbtype-xml-in-procedures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, a simple: `CAST(MyVarcharString AS xml)`

Or assign it to the [SQLDbType.Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971534.aspx) in .net as, say, a parameter

Comment: @TonyP: Updated with SQLDbType.Xml info

Comment: I am not comfortable doing the following , any advice 
sxml = b.BaanSession(sxml);   
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@x", SqlDbType.Xml);
p.Value = sxml;
xmsg =(SqlXml) p.Value;

Comment: This works fairly often but the XML we were receiving and trying to parse used single quotes instead of quotes to encapsulate node attributes and when using CAST and CONVERT the it would throw exceptions.

Answer (score 13):

Another way in pure C# - for posterity:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream))
    {
        xmlWriter.WriteString(xmlData.ToString().Trim());
        return new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml(memoryStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code did not work for me, but put me on the right track. What is a value of xmlData that worked for you? I added my version of the conversion code as an alternative answer.

Comment: I had an issue with this code when the XML data I was trying to write out used a single quote to encapsulate attribute values instead of a quote. The xmlWriter.WriteString failed and generated an error about invalid XML. I actually had to use R. Schreurs code to solve the issue. In all honesty, the reason I had to convert to a SqlXml type instead of just using a string is that SQL Server was also choking on single quote vs quote. I don't falut the code at all, just one of those things where this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 10):

I know this has been answered, but neither of the answers seemed to work for me. Instead I took another approach using this oneliner

`var sqlXml = new SqlXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(stringToParseToSqlXml)));`

However this is leaking, but changing it to:

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(stringToParseToSqlXml))
{
    using (var xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(reader))
    {
        var sqlXml = new SqlXml(xmlreader);
        // Do other stuff
    }
}
```

I've used this, and it seems to works for me.

Comment: Thank you, I was constantly getting the closed object message too. Also I like the using refactor.

Answer (score 7):

This is my version of a C# conversion method.

```
public static SqlXml ConvertString2SqlXml(string xmlData)
{
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(xmlData));
    return new SqlXml(m);
}
```

I am not quite please with it, because I would have liked to have the MemoryStream with a using block, but that gave me:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Invalid attempt to call
>   Read when the stream is closed.'.

I am willing to accept that issue, because this code is only used in unit-tests, where I want to test an SqlFunction with an SqlXml parameter, which will be deployed to the SQL Server CLR.

The answer of ReinhardtB did not work for me, due to the following issues:
When calling this with xmlData `"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><test></test>"` (the back slashes are in the C# string literal), I got:

> System.InvalidOperationException occurred
>   Message=Token Text in state Start would result in an invalid XML document.
>   Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is set to 
>   ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want to
>   write an XML fragment.

This was easily fixed by the following modification:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, settings))
```

However, this led to the following exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedException occurred Message=Cannot access a
>   disposed object. Object name: 'Invalid attempt to call Read when the
>   stream is closed.'. Source=System.Data

This, I could work-around by omitting the using block for the MemoryStream (which is of course a bad idea), just to hit the next issue: when inspecting the value of SqlXml, SqlXml.Value, I found that it contains the value `&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;&lt;test&gt;&lt;/test&gt;`, that is, < and > have been escaped! This looks like a serious issue with the `SqlXml` type.

Comment: faster then "var sqlXml = new SqlXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(stringToParseToSqlXml)));"

Answer (score 1):

SqlParameter works fine if you set the correct length.

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@XML_Field", SqlDbType.Xml, stringXml.Length)
comm.Prepare()
comm.Parameters("@XML_Field").Value = stringXml
```

And -1 if you want to set DBNull.Value in some cases :

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@XML_Field", SqlDbType.Xml, -1)
comm.Prepare()
comm.Parameters("@XML_Field").Value = DBNull.Value
```