# How can I store more than 4000 chars in an SQL Server parameter?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to pass `XML` that is greater than 4000 characters to a stored procedure. I've tried using `NTEXT`, `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, `VARCHAR(MAX)`, `VARCHAR(8000)` and `XML` as the parameter type but I am always getting the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

The value is not being stored into a table, it's only a variable that has data selected out of it and then stored into tables.

Can ASP.NET not send more than 4000 characters as a parameter? Or is there a setting in SQL Server I can switch off?

Thanks,

Thomas

EDIT:

This is working with `NTEXT`. I went into the error details and found what line of the SQL was causing the error and it turns out there was a completely unrelated column set to `VARCHAR(50)` that should have been `VARCHAR(MAX)` - I assumed it was coming from the 10000 character `XML` but it was totally unrelated. My apologies.

Comment: What's the length of that column you're trying to write to in the database?

Comment: If you're passing the value in as a parameter, have you remembered to up the width of the parameter as well as the datatype? That one bites me every so often...

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe I'm not writing the string to a column, I'm selecting smaller bits out data out of the XML to different columns. The >4000 char string is only ever a parameter, it is not written to a table.

Comment: @PhilPursglove What do you mean by this? I'm declaring the parameter like "@XmlString     XML = NULL " and "AddParameter(objCmd, "@XmlString ", SqlDbType.Xml, -1, ParameterDirection.Input, False, strXML)"

Comment: Show us the code so we can point the error, rather than guess. The truncation occurs because your code truncates it.

Comment: Shame you're not using sql-server 2008, I don't believe table-valued param's have a limit

Comment: When you set the parameter value to a string (assuming strXML is a string?) instead of an actual Xml object it will treat it as NVarChar which has a 4k limit. See the answer on this SO question for the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574928/c-sql-whats-wrong-with-sqldbtype-xml-in-procedures

Comment: You shouldn't be using `NTEXT` anymore - it's deprecated and will be removed from SQL Server soon. Use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead - it has all the same beneficial properties and can even be treated just like a "normal" `NVARCHAR(x)` string - use all string functions against it (handling `NTEXT` always was very kludgy)

Comment: Consider deleting the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an sql server limitation in all edition. You can split the xml in two varchar variables and merge them into the stored procedure. It's an workaround for the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Break the XML in smaller chunks and assign them on seperate variable and then concatenate them

DECLARE @SQL1,@SQL2

SET @SQL1=chunk1

SET @SQL2=chunk2

SET @SQLn=chunkn

exec (@SQL1+@SQL2.....+@SQLn)

Answer (score 0):

Seems there are several ways to do this. [This](http://www.codedementia.com/blogs/?p=5) is how I recently went about it.